# Fast solver for Sylvester equation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, sylvester-equation

Is there any available implementation of a fast method to solve a Sylvester equation:

$$AX + XB = C,$$

where, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{$n \times n$}$, $B \in \mathbb{R}^{$p \times p$}$ and $C \in \mathbb{R}^{$n \times p$}$.

In my case, $B$ is a symmetric and large matrix with $p >> n$.

I tried the *solve_sylvester* function from python (scipy.linalg), and the two functions *sylvester* and *lyap* from Matlab as well, but all of them are slow.

Thanks,

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.05493.pdf

Comment: If I remember correctly, solving the general Sylvester equation requires integrating along a contour that contains the eigenvalues of one matrix and not the other or something like that. Doesn't sound fast to me. Maybe you can do something with your special matrix $B$.

Comment: How large is the size of those matrix? Tools like Matlab should be able to solve it quickly. For any non-singular matrix P and Q， we have $PAP^{-1}PXQ^{-1}+PXQ^{-1}QBQ^{-1}=PCQ^{-1}$.
Usually both A and B could be diagonalized after that it is easy to solve $PXQ^{-1}$

Comment: https://stanford.edu/class/ee363/lectures/lq-lyap.pdf may be of some help...

Comment: Jean Marie, quarague & Zhaohui Du, Thank you for your comments.

Comment: @Zhaohui Du, The size of the matrix B is generally > 10$^{5}$. This is a sub-problem of an optimization problem I have. Existing solvers in Matlab and Python are designed for small and medium-size matrices. For large matrices, these solvers are very slow. How to calculate P and Q?

Comment: The matrix size is too large. The time complexity for those eigenvalue related algorithm should be around $O(n^3)$ so it must cost a great amount of computation resource to solve the problem.

Comment: That's why I am looking for a fast method to solve this equation with large matrices.

Comment: How to obtain P and Q given in your formulation. Do you have any related reference?